# Nautilus does not open

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

Clicking on Files/nautilus does not open it. Also when I right-click first and then click on 'open' nothing happens. How to fix?

Comment: Start `terminal` from the Unity Dash. In terminal, type `nautilus`, and post the results to paste.ubuntu.com, and give us the URL so we can look at it. Cheers, Al

Comment: You can also [edit] your question to add the output of running the command `nautilus` in a terminal window.

Comment: @heynnema Only if the author does not correctly apply code formatting in the post editor. however, this can be fixed by the community. The expected output is not too large, so it's generally better to keep all important information on the site itself without relying on external resources.

Comment: @heynnema Check out the relevant section from the help center: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: @heynnema I think I folowed your instruction.. Tnx in advance

Comment: And what happened? Post the results here, by editing your original question, or by paste.ubuntu.com and give us the URL. Cheers, Al

Comment: Nothing happened. Only at the moment Nautilus opens again. I don understand but.. Tnx!